# DropDownList with Textbox in MVC4 razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I need to DropdownList with TextBox under the dropdownLIst. My requirement
there is do not overlap dropdown list on the bottom text box. when i click dropdown list which is automatically adjust height like following image. I have problem getting when i select  dropdown list that point of time it will overlap the bottom textbox. I have using **ASP.NET MVC4 Razor** There is any Jquery Control like this Please help me

I think just show like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Bootstrap's Select2 plugin`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). It allows you to filter the results from the dropdown by typing text into the input field:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks your feed back but there is one problem we need to feeling like dropdownlist with textbox like that image. do not list seperatly. Can you help me

Comment: Hi Darin Dimitrov,
Your are showing dropdownlist with search textbox that is fine I need to that type of dropdownlist with another textbox on bottom side but we are feeling like single control. I have upload that type of image please check it.

Comment: Please help me anyone